# How to setup Admob Mediation on an ionic 2 app?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, admob

How do I setup Admob Mediation to say, Facebook Audience Network or any other external service ?

I  checked this Plugin called [Cordova Admob Pro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) but I would have to share 2% of my ad traffic / revenue with them and I am skeptical of how it would estimate my traffic , so I dont really want to use that.

If it's possible, I am open to integrating the SDKs myself, but is there an easier and legit way?

Answer (score 1):

Plugin **Cordova Admob Pro** is not share with you 2% is more than 30% if you don't pay 20$ for bu licence so try the plugin Cordova Admob here it's free 
[Cordova-plugin-admob](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob)